# gray image log transformation in java

Tags: java, image-processing, transform, bufferedimage

I am trying to get a log transformation from a gray image. But with whatever c value I will get a black image. Any idea?

that is my method:

///---------------------------------------------------

public static BufferedImage log_trans (int[][] imageData , int c){

```
        BufferedImage LogImage = new BufferedImage(imageData.length, imageData[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        double temp;
        for (int i =0 ; i<imageData.length ; i ++){
        for (int j=0 ; j<imageData[0].length ; j++){
                int rgb = imageData[i][j];
                rgb = (rgb<<16)|(rgb<<8)|(rgb);
                temp = Math.log10(rgb+1);
                rgb = (int) (c * temp); 
                LogImage.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
        }}

        return LogImage;
    }

--------------------------------------------------------------
public static int[][] readimage(File filename){
    BufferedImage img;

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(filename);

        // Gray_scaled Image output

        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();
        ImagePro.fw=width;
        ImagePro.fh = height;
        int [][] readimageVal = new int [width][height];
        for (int i = 0; i<height ; i++){
            for (int j =0  ; j<width ; j++){

                Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(j, i));
                   int r= (int)(c.getRed() * 0.299)&0xff;
                   int g = (int)(c.getGreen() * 0.587)&0xff;
                   int b = (int)(c.getBlue() *0.114)&0xff;
                   int avg = ((r+b+g));

                readimageVal[j][i] = avg;
                    }
                    }
        return readimageVal;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that "rgb" is always negative, so temp is always Nan, so in the end "rgb" after:

```
rgb = (int) (c * temp);
```

is always 0 and this is why you always get black picture.

After changing your 8th line to:

rgb = (((byte)rgb & 0xFF)<<16)|(((byte)rgb & 0xFF)<<8)|(((byte)rgb & 0xFF));

I get some very dark output, but it's not very nice. I tested for value of "c" being 1, 18000, 180000 and 0x00FFFFFF.

Comment: @Jedzej : Thank you . I tried your code and as you said it just works for very high values of c. I'va already done what you are suggesting  in my reading image method.May this be related to my image reading method ? I am editing my question by adding image reading method.

Comment: I just ran your code. After removing line: "rgb = (int) (c * temp); " I got pretty nice black & white image. To be honest this logarithm there seems suspicious, could you provide some explanation to this algorithm? I have a feeling that Math.log shouldn't be applied to whole rgb value (so triplet R, G and B), but to separate values of R, G and B. Are you implementing some specific algorithm?

Comment: Ugh, okay, wait a moment. What you pass to your function is already gray image, what you want to do is to apply logarithmic transformation to it. Okay. You must apply logarithm to the value read from an array, multiply by "c" and THEN spread this value into R, G and B (by shifting initial value). Note, that after log(rgb) * c, you can easily get value larger than 255, so more than you can put into single byte, so you should probably clamp this value at 255, so Math.min(rgb, 255), otherwise you will get nearly random values (last bytes of some larger values) which is nonsensical.